# How to set a thread's DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, win32gui, wpf-interop

I'm trying to figure out how I can temporarily disable DPI awareness in a WPF-application to set Window Placement. Following this [example](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/10/24/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-for-desktop-applications-and-mixed-mode-dpi-scaling-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/#ruIqXAc1uOpSRueK.97)

I'm essentially trying to run the following from my Window's code behind:

```
DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT previousDpiContext = SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE);
BOOL ret = SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, wp);
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(previousDpiContext);
```

But I can't figure out how this would work with `interop`. I have set up some basic Window Placement `interop` using the example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidrickard/2010/03/08/saving-window-size-and-location-in-wpf-and-winforms/)

Comment: Pretty doubtful that this is what you really want to do.  Google "wpf convert inches to pixels" for possible solutions.

Comment: Typically, WPF is pretty much DPI aware - or should be. It's often different for WinForms, and some components might also have DPI issues.